# PHP Mongo Session Handler and Sharding

Tags: php, mongodb, session

I am using

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MongoDbSessionHandler.php

as my session handler for my PHP app.

Our app is expecting high volume traffic, so we are experimenting with sharding the Mongo that store session.

I have set up my shard according the the document, and things are all fine before I shard the collection (I can see session document being created in the `session` collection).

As soon as I enabled sharding on `session` using sharding key `sess_id`, then no session document gets created (i.e. count never change), and I see these lines in the `mongos` log whenever I visit my PHP page:
`resetting shard version of mydb.session on my.hsard.ip.address:port, version is zero`

I have tried to shard my other collection and it works fine, so that tells me my sharding setup is correct.

Anybody have a clue of what might be wrong? I'm using Mongo 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause.

It was because the `write` function in `MongoDbSessionHandler.php` that comes with symfony version we are using will not work with sharding.

The `MongoDbSessionHandler.php` we are using implements `write` like this:

```
$mongo->update({shardkey:1}, {shardkey:1, data:2}, {upsert:true})
```

which is not allowed, because you cannot change the shard key.

Solution is to simply use the latest version of `MongoDbSessionHandler.php` in the github.